# Enable migrations with reference to ApplicationUser identity framework code first

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, code-migration

I'll create a database with identity framework (code first way) but I've errors when I run code below in the package manager.

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName FreeTime.AspMvc.Context.FreeTimeContext -Force
```

Here are my errors:

> - *`IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType IdentityUserLogin`* has no key defined. Define the key for this `EntityType`.
> - *`IdentityUserRole: : EntityType IdentityUserRole`* has no key defined. Define the key for this `EntityType`.
> - *`IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet IdentityUserLogins`* is based on type `IdentityUserLogin` that has no keys defined.
> - *`IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet IdentityUserRoles`* is based on type `IdentityUserRole` that has no keys defined.

More information:

[image: More information]
<sup>(Click to see full screen)</sup>

In other classes I've made a property type of `ApplicationUser` named `UserId` and one of type of string named `User` for holding witch user has made witch topic. Here you've an example:

```
public class Topic 
{
    [Key]
    public int TopicId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers.Id")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

**Small update:** Here is my context file:

```
public class FreeTimeContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

I've also seen that there is a second context file named `ApplicationDbContext`.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("FreeTimeContext" /* --> this I've edited into my own name */,
               throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

---

**Big update:** In a later state I've tried other things like list below:

1. First I've tried to enabled the migrations for `ApplicationDbContext`. Here are the steps I've done.

   - First I've run this code:

     ```
     PM> enable-migrations -ContextTypeName FreeTime.AspMvc.Models.ApplicationDbContext -Force
     ```

     This is done without errors.
   - Then I've run this:

     ```
     PM> add-migration "initAspTables"
     ```

     Also no problems with this code.
   - Finaly I've update my database:

     ```
     PM> Update-Database
     ```

     Also done with no problems.
   - Check if the tables are created into the server manager → Check but doesn't contain my own tables. ☹

     [image: Object explorer from server manager with my database and the tables.]

   **Conclusion:** not really what I will have.
2. Second thing I've done is inherit `FreeTimeContext` from `ApplicationContext` instead of `DbContext` like code below.

   ```
   public class FreeTimeContext: ApplicationDbContext
   {
       public DbSet Topics { get; set; }

       public FreeTimeContext(): base() 
       { }
       // other code
   }
   ```

   And again to try enable the migrations with this code:

   ```
   PM> enable-migrations -ContextTypeName FreeTime.AspMvc.Context.FreeTimeContext -Force
   ```

   but I've this error:

   > The `ForeignKeyAttribute` on property `UserId` on type `FreeTime.AspMvc.Models.Topic` is not valid. The navigation property `dbo.AspNetUsers.Id` was not found on the dependent type `FreeTime.AspMvc.Models.Topic`. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

   More information:

   [image: More information]<sup>(Click to see full screen)</sup>

   **Conclusion:** didn't work.

Can you help me? I don't know what else I could do to migrate the class `ApplicationUser` together with my own classes to the database.

Comment: I usually just hijack the Identity context; I rename it if needed, update all the references to it, then add my objects to that so that there is only one context. It makes integrating the identity objects with the rest of the domain objects easier too.

Comment: @H. Pauwelyn ... I am facing the same problem. Did you find solution to this?